# Custom Navigation and Header Area in Genesis Framework

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to customize the navigation and header region of my Genesis 2 theme. Here is the code I'm using:

```
/* Reposition the primary navigation menu
remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );

function new_header(){ ?>
<div id="title-area">
    <div id="new-title">
<h1>new Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="new-nav">
<nav class="nav-primary" role="navigation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"><div class="wrap">
 <?php
    add_action( 'genesis_do_nav' );
?></div>
</nav>
</div>
<div id="new-search">
<p>Search Box will need to go in here</p>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
}

add_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'new_header' );
```

The title is printing out fine, and the paragraph where I will want to add my search box is printing fine too. HOwever, for some reason I am not getting any output for my menu.

What am I missing? THere is nothing being printed at all when I inspect the element.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you alter the CSS of each of these elements the default way Genesis provides it? The only thing I see that is different from the default way is that you want a search box underneath the navigation.

If that's the case, then just add the function for the search box and position it after the nav. For example check below

```
add_action('genesis_after_header', 'move_my_nav');
function move_my_nav() {
  echo '<div id="new-search">';
  echo '<p>Search Box will need to go in here</p>';
  echo '</div>';
}
```